# Remove standard SAS libraries from GUI

Tags: sas

I'd like to remove/delete/unassign the standard SAS libraries from my SAS 9.3 GUI.

I've tried two solutions to remove a library which haven't worked:

1. `%sysfunc(libname(maps))` results in:

`ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.`

2. Comment out the offending start up code in the file sasv9.cfg

I don't have permission to modify (C:\Program Files...) files in that directory

Thanks!

The libraries are:
 - Maps

- Mapsgfk
- Mapssas
- Sashelp
- Sasuser

Comment: which GUI are you referring to?  Presumably Enterprise Guide? Is there a reason why you'd want to remove these?  They are system libraries and generally shouldn't be tinkered with..

Comment: Not Enterprise Guide. SAS 9.3. I'm not trying to tinker/delete actual datasets, just remove from the list

Comment: interesting question!

Comment: my current install also has the config file locked down.  If changing the options there doesn't work, I'd probably suggest using AF / SCL to build an explorer window with just the libraries you want..

Comment: What about adding them to the autoexec to deassign them?

Comment: exactly, I don't mind running code to remove them -- I just don't want them clogging up my useful libs

Comment: Apparently MAPS and MAPSGFK are livable without, but not SASHELP or SASUSER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the map related libnames, at the cost of not having the map files available to you and possibly losing some functionality.

If you copy your basic config file to some other location, either to one of the predefined locations mentioned in [Files Used By SAS](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/69955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0bmj7wjme32ayn1h4wim7trkhp6.htm#p1f8pahglb6jz0n18i9bd3xxl84r) for your operating system (I link to the Windows version here, but Unix has a [similar page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/69602/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p13flc1vsrqwr8n1vutzds8rp3t0.htm));  or to a location specified on the `-CONFIG` option in your shortcut, like for example:

```
"C:\Program Files\SAS94\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe" -CONFIG "C:\temp\sasv9_nolibs.cfg"
```

You can do this without having write access to the Program Files directories where the config files are usually stored. If you do that, you can then customize it by removing the -MAPS and related lines.  Then those libraries will not be created; in that case, only SASHELP, SASUSER, and WORK are created, as follows:

[image: Image of SAS with only three libraries]

Removing SASUSER does not seem to be possible, as while you can remove the `-SASUSER` option in the config file, it will still create the SASUSER folder.

Removing the `-SASHELP` option will unfortunately cause SAS to crash on initialization; SASHELP contains many core files for SAS functionality and SAS cannot work without it.  See the following screenshot.

[image]

As such, you can get down to 3 libraries, but not further.

Comment: I believe there's an option when installing SAS to have the maps libraries set up. Mine aren't set up by default, I'll have to get a SR to our IT team to have them populated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can remove them without changing your system wide config.sas file. But you could point the MAPS options to null devices so that they don't find any datasets. Here is output from PROC OPTIONS.

```
 MAPS=!SASROOT/maps
                   Specifies the location of SAS/GRAPH map data sets.
 MAPSGFK=!SASROOT/mapsgfk
                   Specifies the location of GfK maps.
 MAPSSAS=!SASROOT/maps
                   Specifies the location of SAS map data sets.
```

You can point these two different locations with command line options.

```
sas -maps /dev/nul  -mapsgfk /dev/nul -mapssas /dev/nul
```

The libref will still be created but there won't be any members found.

You might do something similar for SASUSER, but then you would probably also want to add `-rsasuser` option so that SAS would know to create a WORK.PROFILE to use in place of the normal SASUSER.PROFILE catalog.

I don't think you would want to remove SASHELP libref as I think there are a number of things in SAS that would not work without being able to find things that are made available via that libref.

Answer (score 0):

You got the 180-322 because the libname function returns a value and you call it in open code and the code it generated is not valid.

```
29         %put NOTE: %sysfunc(libname(maps));
NOTE: -630193
```

Do as above an you will see the value.  However it looks like you cannot clear LIBREF MAPS.